# How do you hide href="dummy1" attachment to link when clicked on?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the href link attachment to my browser link when I click on each href. For example, when I click on the href="dummy1" I don't want it to show mydomain.com/#dummy1. I want to hide the #dummy1 part. Hope this question makes sense.

Each hypertext scrolls down to a different part of my page.

Here is my CSS and HTML code

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #000;
    min-height: 200vh;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
}

header .logo {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

header.sticky {
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(IMG-1022.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

header.sticky .logo,
header.sticky ul li a {
    color: #000;
}

#home {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#aboutMe {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#portfolio {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#contact {
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    background-color: purple;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#dummy1,
#dummy2,
#dummy3 {
    margin-top: -65px;
}

#aboutMe,
#portfolio, 
#contact {
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=chrome">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexStyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="favicon.img"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">My Name</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#dummy1">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#dummy2">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#dummy3">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <section class="banner"></section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
            var header = document.querySelector("header");
            header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 100);
        })
    </script>
    <div id="dummy1"></div>
    <div id="aboutMe">This is the about me section</div>
    <div id="dummy2"></div>
    <div id="portfolio">This is the portfolio section</div>
    <div id="dummy3"></div>
    <div id="contact">This is the contact me section</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to look up URL rewrite engine. If you're using an APACHE server as your web server, then there are ways to achieve this in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achived by setting the `href` property to `href=""` and by attaching a onClick event to the `<a>` tag to redirect the link after clicking.
In the end, it should look like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="location.href='https://yourSite.com'+'#dummy1'">Your text.</a>
```

Comment: That goes to the dummy1 div section but then it shoots back up to the top no matter what I do.

Comment: This could be a behaviour from putting the href property to an empty string. You can try to put it to href="#" to see if it fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can use JavaScript. Bind your link to a clickevent and set the link target via JS and jump there. This way you can manipulate the link as you like.

```js
function jump (target) {    
  window.location = '#' + target;  
  return false;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #000;
    min-height: 200vh;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    padding: 40px 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
}

header .logo {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

header.sticky {
    padding: 5px 100px;
    background: #fff;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(IMG-1022.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

header.sticky .logo,
header.sticky ul li a {
    color: #000;
}

#home {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#aboutMe {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color: orange;
}

#portfolio {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#contact {
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    background-color: purple;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#dummy1,
#dummy2,
#dummy3 {
    margin-top: -65px;
}

#aboutMe,
#portfolio, 
#contact {
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=chrome">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexStyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="favicon.img"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">My Name</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a onclick="return jump( 'dummy1')" href="dummy1">About Me</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a onclick="return jump( 'dummy2')" href="dummy2">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a onclick="return jump( 'dummy1')" href="dummy3">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <section class="banner"></section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
            var header = document.querySelector("header");
            header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 100);
        })
    </script>
    <div id="dummy1"></div>
    <div id="aboutMe">This is the about me section</div>
    <div id="dummy2"></div>
    <div id="portfolio">This is the portfolio section</div>
    <div id="dummy3"></div>
    <div id="contact">This is the contact me section</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```